# Livewire dispatching event modal with a dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, events, laravel-livewire

Im trying to show the user the times when he's available by days and display them in a modal.

```php
public function searchAvailability(){
        $this->validate();
        $doctor = Doctor::where('id',$this->selectedDoctor)->first(); 
        $doctorTimes = DoctorTime::where('doctor_id',$this->selectedDoctor)->get();
        $parsedDate = Carbon::parse($this->selectedDate);

        $dayName = $parsedDate->format('l');
        
        if ($parsedDate->isFuture()) {
            foreach($doctorTimes as $doctorTime){
                if ($doctorTime->day == $dayName) {
                    $this->availableOn = DoctorTime::where('doctor_id',$this->selectedDoctor)
                    ->where('day',$doctorTime->day)->where('is_taken',0)->get();
                }
            }
            if (count($this->availableOn) > 0) {
                $this->dispatch('loading-success',
                title: 'Search Availability',
                );
            }
}


protected $listeners = ['showModal' => 'showTimesModal','loadingFailed' => 'failed'];

public function showTimesModal() { 
    $this->dispatch('appointment-modal',availableOn: $this->availableOn);
}
```

here im listening for the events:

```js
window.addEventListener('loading-success', (event) =>{ 
    let data = event.detail
    let timerInterval;

    Swal.fire({
        title: data.title,
        timer: 2000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: () => {
            Swal.showLoading();
            const timer = Swal.getPopup().querySelector("b");
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                timer.textContent = `${Swal.getTimerLeft()}`;
            }, 100);
        },
        willClose: () => {
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
            Livewire.dispatch('showModal');
        }
    });
})
```

```php
protected $listeners = ['showModal' => 'showTimesModal','loadingFailed' => 'failed'];`


public function showTimesModal(){         
    $this->dispatch('appointment-modal',availableOn: $this->availableOn);         
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade"  id="showTimes" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="showTimes" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> ...

@script
    $wire.on('appointment-modal', (availableOn) =\> {
        console.log(availableOn);
        const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#showTimes');
        myModal.show();
    });
@endscript
```

I have tried to loop on the data like that

```js
availableOn.forEach(time => { 
    let timeElement = document.createElement('p'); 
    timeElement.textContent = time.start_time + ' - ' + time.end_time; 
    modalBody.appendChild(timeElement) 
    const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#showTimes'); 
    myModal.show();
```

but the modal disappear!

Overall, the code orchestrates the flow of searching for availability, displaying a success message, and showing the modal window with available times using Laravel (PHP), JavaScript (with SweetAlert and Livewire), and Bootstrap for styling the modal.

Comment: Unrelated, but your code is really inefficient... You can reduce most of your code to `$this->availableOn = DoctorTime::where('doctor_id', $this->selectedDoctor)->where('day', $parsedDate->format('l'))->where('is_taken', 0)->get()`, and get rid of the entire `foreach(...) { ... }`... You're iterating over your results to simply query your table _again_ **for the same results**...

Comment: "but the modal disappear!" - Apologies for not understanding this part. Is the modal opening and closing at once? Or, if that's not the case, is the modal opening, but not showing up (for example, only the transparent black background is showing, instead of the expected modal body with appropriate data)? Can you attach an event listener for `modal.bs.hidden`, and add a `console.log(...)` inside of it? This is to verify that the modal isn't opening and closing right after opening.

Comment: @FiddlingAway - The modal is not showing at all, because the 'availableOn' type is returning an object! , but when I console log the 'availableOn' it return an array like that: {availableOn: Array(2)}, that's so wierd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous code, I had a problem because I was passing availableOn as an argument. That's why it didn't work. Here is the correct code:
@script

```
    $wire.on('appointment-modal', async (event) => {
    let data = await event.availableOn; 
    console.log(data);
    
    const modalBody = document.getElementById('modal-body'); 
    data.forEach(time => { 
        console.log(time.day)
    let timeElement = document.createElement('p'); 
    timeElement.textContent = time.start_time + ' - ' + time.end_time; 
    modalBody.appendChild(timeElement);
    });
    const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#showTimes'); 
    myModal.show();

    });
</script>
@endscript
```

Answer (score 0):

Livewire will repaint the HTML elements unless you instruct it otherwise. Do to so, you can add `wire:ignore.self`, which will tell Livewire to not modify that element.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="showTimes" wire:ignore.self tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="showTimes" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"> 
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                ...
```

See the related Livewire documentation: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-ignore